# How do I upgrade RedShop from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5?

Tags: joomla

I have recently upgraded many of our 1.5 Joomla sites to 2.5, and most of the work was straight-forward. I used the jupgrade and redMigrator tools, and they do most of the heavy-lifting. I have upgraded the templates and some of the custom extensions myself, but have now run into a wall with redShop.

I have looked around for a step-by-step guide for this component upgrade (I've read the boilerplate upgrade info from Joomla many times), but still haven't found anything that makes sense or actually works. So I attempted it on my own and got this far:

1. I completed the core upgrade and have the new 2.5 site running well.
2. Joomla templates are updated, installed and running correctly.
3. I manually transferred the redShop db tables to the new db.
4. I manually moved the redShop image assets from the 1.5 site to the 2.5 site.
5. I installed the new version of redShop on the new site, which left the manually migrated data in-place.
6. RedShop is installed and running, but the data and assets are not being shown.

So now I have the new version installed, and the old existing data is in the db. The main menu contains the items from the 1.5 site, and they point to redShop pages for redShop categories. Those categories are there, but the trouble is, when I click on a menu link, and go to one of the cat pages, none of the images are present, and none of the individual products are there. So it's not displaying any actual store items or the associated meta data.

I feel like I'm nearly there with what I've done to move the store, but I have obviously missed some critical thing.

Anyone have some sage advice for me?

Comment: Maybe you should contact the developers of redShop. They will be able to give you a good in-depth answer

Comment: The redComponent team is horrible at support... having dealt with them over the years, I'm not at all confident I'd get a suitable answer :-\